# writeCopyToPath Realm Doesn't work

Tags: realm

I try to follow "Bundling a Realm with an App" Documentation.I've try to use method `Realm().writeCopyToPath(_:encryptionKey:))` but the problem is i can't make a file on a specific location on my OSX. It's show error that file already exits. Please give me a correct way to use writeCopyToPath

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!, error: nil)

    // Create a standalone object
    var mydog = Dog()

    // Set & read properties
    mydog.name = "Rex"
    mydog.age = 9
    println("Name of dog: \(mydog.name)")

    // Realms are used to group data together
    let realm = Realm() // Create realm pointing to default file
    println(realm.writeCopyToPath("/Users/taforyou/CU-TEP",encryptionKey: nil))

    // Save your object
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.add(mydog)
    realm.commitWrite()
    return true
}
}
```

Output Log When running

```
Name of dog: Rex
Optional(Error Domain=io.realm Code=4 "open() failed: File exists" UserInfo=0x7fbc704a8cd0 {NSLocalizedDescription=open() failed: File exists, Error Code=4})
```

Thank you

realm 0.95

Answer (score 2):

The error message getting printed says it all: the file you're trying to create (`/Users/taforyou/CU-TEP`) already exists. Note that the path that `writeCopyToPath` is expecting is a full path to the resulting realm file (`/path/to/file.realm`, not `/path/to`) just in case `CU-TEP` is actually a directory.